# Can't connect to socket after emit

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am working on project that involves real time temperatures and have a device sending temps via get that is routed through the server and emitted to the socket.  Then I want the server to connect to the original socket and emit the data to a new one that is being read by my client.

Here is my app.js

```
    var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    server = require('http').createServer(app),
    io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

server.listen(8080);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});


app.route('/:temp')
   .get(function (req, res){
        var temp = req.params.temp;
        res.end(temp);
        io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
            socket.emit('send temp', temp);
        });
    });

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('send temp', function(data){
        console.log('connected to send temp');//this never shows in the console
        io.sockets.emit('new temp', data);
    });
});
```

The route code in app.js works fine.  When I hit localhost:3000/test and change the client to connect to 'send temp' (rather then 'new temp') 'test' is output.

Here is the relevant section of my client

```
var socket = io.connect();
        var $temp = $('#temp');         


        socket.on('new temp', function(data){
            $temp.html("Temp: " + "<br/>"+data);
        });
```

I am running node version 4.1.2, socket 1.3.7 and express 4.10.8.
I am wondering why I cannot connect to the original socket a second time.  Or that may not even be my problem.  I have studied the many 'chat' tutorials and searched for others using trying to do what I want to without any success.

Ultimately what I am trying to have happen is have a client hit /:temp over and over with a real-time reading and then have other clients get that data in real-time.

This is all still a little new to me so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code example registers a message handler on the server for the `'send temp'` message.  The client registers a message handler for the `'new temp'` message.

The two (client and server) are then sitting there in a stalemate waiting for someone to first send a message, but (per the code you've disclosed) nobody ever does.

I don't really understand what the intent is for your code, but I see several issues.

First off, you do not want to install a listener for the `connection` event inside this code:

```
app.route('/:temp')
   .get(function (req, res){
        var temp = req.params.temp;
        res.end(temp);
        io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
            socket.emit('send temp', temp);
        });
    });
```

Why would you only start listening for a connection event when you get a particular route handler.  And, why add yet another event handler every time that route is hit.  This code is just completely wrong.  I don't know what you thought you were trying to achieve with it, but it's not the way to do things.

Second off, this code is waiting for the client to send a `'send temp'` message and when it gets one, it attempts to broadcast that to all clients.  But, the part of your client you disclose never sends a `'send temp'` message.

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('send temp', function(data){
        console.log('connected to send temp');//this never shows in the console
        io.sockets.emit('new temp', data);
    });
});
```

Third off, please describe exactly what you're trying to accomplish in words so we can better know what code to recommend in order to do that.

---

**EDIT**

Now that you've described the actual problem here:

> Ultimately what I am trying to have happen is have a client hit /:temp
>   over and over with a real-time reading and then have other clients get
>   that data in real-time.

It is a little easier to recommend a solution:

On the server:

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    server = require('http').createServer(app),
    io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

server.listen(8080);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});


app.get('/:temp', function (req, res) {
     var temp = req.params.temp;
     res.end(temp);
     // send this temperature to all connected clients
     io.emit('new temp', temp);
});
```

On the client:

```
var socket = io.connect();
var $temp = $('#temp');         
socket.on('new temp', function(data){
    $temp.html("Temp: " + "<br/>"+data);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time.  I updated to add some clarity and explain what I am trying to do.  I think I am approaching this wrong but look forward to your feedback.

Comment: @cTwice - Based on your description of the actual problem you're trying to solve, I added a new section to the end of my answer.

Comment: That is what I was looking for, appreciate the help.